# Magento SQL unknown query

Tags: database, sql, php-7

We are seeing this SQL query in our DB and are unsure what is generating this, we have flat catalog index enabled so it should not be asking for this

```sql
select `e`.*, if(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) as `visibility`, if(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) as `status`, `cat_index`.`position` as `cat_index_position`, `at_inventory_in_stock`.`is_in_stock` as `inventory_in_stock` from `catalog_product_entity` as `e` inner join `catalog_product_entity_int` as `at_visibility_default` on (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) and (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '102') and `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0 left join `catalog_product_entity_int` as `at_visibility` on (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) and (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') and (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1) inner join `catalog_product_entity_int` as `at_status_default` on (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) and (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '96') and `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0 left join `catalog_product_entity_int[...]
```

Anyone knows why is this and where is this being generated from?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Magento version not mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a regular query that retrieves a list of products filtered by status active.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply, yes i figure that, but it is puttin huge load on server, and my site is way too slow over 100 sec for home page, and i dont have any product at all on home page., shoudnt enabling flat_category index resolve this? as it shouldnt be then requesting this much data in each url request? as for server i have huge server with 2 gold xeon CPU's with 16core each so server is not the problem, i have tried changing server as well and no use.